# Geom_line and fill don't work together in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

it seems that `geom_line` interferes with `aes(fill=)` since:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length,
                 fill = Petal.Width))+
  geom_point(shape = 21)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="orange",high="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(cyl, am), mtcars)
```

Gives me:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object "Petal.Width" not found
```

Any explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to nullify `fill` for your second plot since `mtcars` does not have `Petal.Width` variable.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length,
                 fill = Petal.Width))+
  geom_point(shape = 21)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="orange",high="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(cyl, am, fill=NULL), mtcars)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `geom_line()` inherits global plot aesthetics from the main call to `ggplot()`. Since the `geom_line()` data doesn't have a `Petal.Width` column, the layer cannot find the fill information for that layer (nor is it used for a line). In order to omit these, you can set `inherit.aes = FALSE` or move the offending aesthetic to the correct layers.

Example of `inherit.aes`

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length,
                 fill = Petal.Width))+
  geom_point(shape = 21)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="orange",high="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(cyl, am), mtcars, inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Example of moving the fill aesthetic:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point(aes(fill = Petal.Width), shape = 21)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="orange",high="blue")+
  geom_line(aes(cyl, am), mtcars)
```